# How to do ArangoDB geo index for multiple location[lat,lon]

Tags: arangodb, aql, arangojs

I tried to do Geo Index for a job post platform.
I have a job post object which could have multiple locations[lat,lon].
I've read and tried everything on the official documents but I can only do GeoIndex with one location.
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/indexing-geo.html#multipoint
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-geo.html#geo_distance

I want to do Geo index on locations[lat,lon] field with multiple lat and lon values.

Please help

Comment: If LFNL's anwser did solve your problem, please accept it - that helps others facing the same issue; if not, try to ask better questions by e.g. providing concrete code/data examples, not just verbal descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of locations you can set up an [array-index](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/indexing-index-basics.html#indexing-array-values).

collection.ensureIndex({
type: "geo",
fields: [ "locations[*]" ],
geoJson:true
})